# PowerShell FileSystemWatcher exit while ($true)

Tags: powershell

I need this script to loop until it does the action but I can't seem to break the loop.

```cs
# SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\TransX\InputTriggers\"
$watcher.Filter = "IVANS_TRIGGER_FILE.trig"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, Ivans File Arrived"
    Add-Content "C:\TransX\InputTriggers\ProcessLog.txt" -Value $logline
    Start-Process C:\TransX\Transxdl.bat
    Remove-Item C:\TransX\InputTriggers\IVANS_TRIGGER_FILE.trig

    break
}

# DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
#Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
#Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $stopScript
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

The `break` command in the `$action` isn't working.

Comment: What's the point of the infinite loop?

Comment: Of course that doesn't work. How do you expect to a command to break out of a loop when it isn't *in* the loop in the first place? Have the action create a file, a registry key, a log entry, or something like that, and have the loop poll that resource until it appears. Something like `do {Start-Sleep 5} until (Test-Path 'C:\some\file.txt')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BREAK` and `CONTINUE` will only work this way when used inside a loop, your action is not in the loop itself.

What you could try, is using a variable like `$ContinueWatching` for your loop and switch it from the Action.

Example:

```
$ContinueWatching = $true

$Action = {

    # <Your code here>
    # <Remove break>

    # StopWatching and Exit Script
    $global:ContinueWatching = $false
}

While ($ContinueWatching) {
    Start-Sleep -s 1
}
```